# How to filter two different type of arrays ( remove duplicate data ) using angular 6?

Tags: angular, typescript

```js
array1 = ["one","two"];

array2 = [ {"name":"one","id":101} , {"name":"two","id":102} , {"name":"three","id":103} , {"name":"four","id":104} ];
```

in the above data, `array1` is a collection of string values, `array2` is a collection of objects. Now how to remove `array1` related values in `array2`. I wrote code using for loops but it was too long so any predefined methods exist in angular-6/typescript.

Output:

```
array2 = [ {"name":"three","id":103} , {"name":"four","id":104} ];
```

Comment: look for array.filter and the indexOf function...

Answer (score 5):

> You can leverage `filter` and `includes`.

```
let finalArray = array2.filter(item=>!array1.includes(item.name))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can filter with checking the `index` of the name in `array1`

```
const array3 = array2.filter((item) => array1.indexOf(item.name) < 0);
```